# Multiple update of the same sql table in c#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, web-services

I have a web service that can be accessed from a win form.
The web service accesses the database (MS Sql) in order to preform actions of update \ delete \ create on the tables' rows, according to the user choice on the winform.

What will happen if various users will run the winform and preform an update on the same table row?
will it be locked by the database?

Answer (score 0):

That depends entirely things like the isolation level of both connections. However, done naively, the final outcome is rather unpredictable. In reality, changes happen quickly, so it is a race condition and will be hard to reproduce (for testing etc) reliably. It may be worthwhile using something like `rowversion` checking for concurrency / consistency - at least then you can predict the results.